# Why this Dafny example verification fails?

Tags: dafny

This is an example to learn Dafny.

```
method test5(x:array<int>,y:array<int>,n:int)
requires 0<=n
requires 0< x.Length
requires 0< y.Length  
requires x[0]==y[0]; 
requires (x[0]>=0 ==> y[0]>=0)
requires  (y[0]>= 0 ==> x[0]>= 0)
requires  (x[0]+y[0]==0 || x[0]+y[0]>0);
modifies y;  
modifies x; 
ensures  (x[0]==y[0]); 
ensures (x[0]>0 ==> y[0]>0)
ensures (y[0] > 0 ==> x[0] > 0)
ensures  (x[0]+y[0]==0 || x[0]+y[0]>0)     
{     if (x[0]>0)
    {x[0]:=x[0]- 1; 
     y[0]:=y[0]- 1;
     }
}
```

Why does the verification fails?

Can Dafny show a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get a counterexample. If you're using Visual Studio, simply click on the red circle where the error is. This brings up the Verification Debugger. If you're using VS Code, then press F7 (see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=correctnessLab.dafny-vscode). That will reverify your program and show you some information from the counterexample.

In your case, these counterexamples show `x` and `y` as being equal and with `x[0]==y[0]==1` initially. Indeed, starting from that initial state, `test5` will not establish its declared postcondition.

Rustan